# identifing UDP packets those have same checksum value

Tags: python

I am trying to identify the UDP packets which have same checksum value in captured wire shark PCAP file 
some please help me how to extract packets those have same checksum value using python program

Comment: Please make a start and see if you can get somewhere. Then it will be easier to get help because Writing code from scratch for you takes a long time, but fixing smaller problems in your code is faster.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.It's coming out well as of now.Will be completing soon.Your advice is greatly appreciated .In case I come across any issues ,i will surely intimidate you.